# Append matrices using numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Given two matrices, `X` and `Y`, I want to combine them into one `Numpy` array. I use `M = np.empty(shape=(0, 2))`
to be an initial empty array and then append `X` and `Y`. However, I cannot find such append method something like `M.append(X)` and `M.append(Y)`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: `np.concatenate((X, Y), axis=0)`?

Comment: @Psidom Thanks for your response. This will merge X and Y but I want to just put them together in one array something like a nested array of [X,Y]

Comment: `np.stack((X, Y))` or just `np.array([X, Y])`.